# Equivalent to Dunnett's test for binomial endpoint?

Tags: anova, binomial-distribution, type-i-and-ii-errors, dunnett, multiplicity

I have a trial comparing 2 treatments vs a control group.  Typically one would use Dunnett's test for this situation, but the outcome measure is binomial.  It seems strange to me but I've looked for the equivalent version of a Dunnett's test for binomial endpoints and not been successful in finding one.  Can anyone suggest which test I should use?  I need to ensure I control multiplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy, if you recognize the parallel construction of regressions when you have a categorical predictor and consider a continuous versus a binary outcome. Say you code `treatment` as a 3-level categorical predictor with "control" as the reference category.

[Dunnett's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnett%27s_test) could be applied to a model like this in R:

```
lm(continuousOutcome ~ treatment)
```

which returns an intercept representing the estimated outcome in the control group and coefficients representing the *difference* of each of the treatment groups from control. Dunnett's test then effectively evaluates the differences of each of those treatment-group coefficients from 0, with correction for multiple comparisons.

With a binary outcome, the following logistic regression in R:

```
glm(binaryOutcome ~ treatment, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

returns an intercept representing the *log-odds* of the outcome for the control group and coefficients representing the *difference* in log-odds for each of the treatment groups from control. So you similarly evaluate the treatment-group coefficients for differences from 0, with correction for multiple comparisons.

The continuous and binary-outcome models involve different assumptions about the distributions of the coefficient estimates, so Dunnett's test can't be used directly with the logistic regression. This is conveniently handled for a wide range of models, including logistic regression, by the ["trt.vs.ctrl" contrasts](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html#contrasts) in the R [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans), which provides "a close approximation to the Dunnett adjustment."

Comment: Thank you; this makes sense to me statistically, although I wish there were a formal test name that I could use.  This analysis will be going in an official report and it's hard to say I used a test in an R package which is a close approximation to the Dunnett test.

Comment: @Bosley with only 2 treatment groups versus control, you might instead use the [Holm-Bonferroni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm–Bonferroni_method) correction for multiple comparisons. If the lowest p-value of the 2 binomial regression coefficients for `treatment` is at or above 0.05/2 = 0.025 then you cannot reject either null hypothesis of a treatment coefficient being equal to 0. If it's below that, reject the corresponding null hypothesis and proceed to the second coefficient. If the p-value for that is below 0.05, you reject that null hypothesis also.

Comment: @Bosley you should be able to cite "the 'dunnettx' multiple-comparison correction in the R emmeans package" if what you want is a name to correspond the to `emmeans` analysis.

Comment: Thanks @Edm.  I was going to go with Holm or Hochberg if nothing panned out for Dunnett, so I appreciate your input!  And thank you for the citation advice.